# Multiple Word Highlighting in Java

Tags: java, highlight

I'm trying to make a word search engine that finds words with a wildcard search, and highlights all of the words it finds. I have got the search going, but the highlighter will only highlight the first word it finds. Say I search for '*hat', all of the instances of 'that' are highlighted, but it does not highlight any other words such as 'what' (even though they are returned to the console as found).

Here is my code for the highlighter, the string returned by the pattern matcher are passed to this method:

```
public static void highlighter(String s){
    String text = displayString.getText();
    highlightStr = new DefaultHighlighter();
    painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.pink);
    displayString.setHighlighter(highlightStr); 
    //highlightStr.removeAllHighlights();

    for(int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++){        
        int start = text.indexOf(s, index);

        try{
            int end = start + s.length();
            highlightStr.addHighlight(start, end, painter);
            displayString.setCaretPosition(end);
        }catch(BadLocationException e){} 
    }
}
```

To be sure that the strings are all being passed to the highlighter I have printed them from the method.

Comment: This thing will repeatedly highlight same words over and over again if their start index is beyond that of the current iteration. Consider if that will be a problem. I suggest changing the for-loop to a while-loop on the condition that `text.indexOf()` doesn't return `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution took me a few attempts of trying, but now it works. It seems to do what you want, and the code appears quite straight-forward to me (at least when I read it now).

I'm using regular expressions to do the text matching (classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`), since they make the code pretty simple. Therefore the wildcard pattern first needs to be translated to a regular expression by the `compileWildcard` method.

```
package so27470328;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter.HighlightPainter;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(25, 80);
    textarea.setText("I'm trying to make a word search engine ... method.");
    Highlighter highlighter = new DefaultHighlighter();
    final DefaultHighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.pink);
    textarea.setHighlighter(highlighter);

    final JTextField highlight = new JTextField(80);
    highlight.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

      private void updateHighlights() {
        highlight(textarea, highlight.getText(), painter);
      }

      @Override
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateHighlights();
      }

      @Override
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateHighlights();
      }

      @Override
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updateHighlights();
      }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(highlight, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(textarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void highlight(JTextArea textarea, String textToHighlight,
      HighlightPainter painter) {
    String text = textarea.getText();
    Highlighter highlighter = textarea.getHighlighter();
    highlighter.removeAllHighlights();

    if (!textToHighlight.isEmpty()) {
      Matcher m = compileWildcard(textToHighlight).matcher(text);
      while (m.find()) {
        try {
          highlighter.addHighlight(m.start(), m.end(), painter);
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(e); /* cannot happen */
        }
        textarea.setCaretPosition(m.end());
      }
    }
  }

  public static Pattern compileWildcard(String wildcard) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\\b"); /* word boundary */
    /* the following replaceAll is just for performance */
    for (char c : wildcard.replaceAll("\\*+", "*").toCharArray()) {
      if (c == '*') {
        sb.append("\\S*"); /*- arbitrary non-space characters */
      } else {
        sb.append(Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(c)));
      }
    }
    sb.append("\\b"); /* word boundary */
    return Pattern.compile(sb.toString());
  }

}
```